CakePHP in Subdirectoy on Nginx Reverse Proxy to Docker Running Apache
I have nginx running as a reverse proxy and I am trying to load my CakePHP site on the docker container in a subdirectory. The docker container is running Apache. I do not want the subdirectory in the URL.
I am able to get the content of the site to load, but none of the supporting files (e.g. CSS, JS, etc) are loading since it (I think Apache) can't find the webroot folder. Here is my nginx conf file:
    listen 80;
    server_name test.org www.test.org *.test.org;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.3:8080;  # Ensure this is the correct IP and port
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 break;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
        #root /var/www/html/subdirectory/webroot/$1;
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        internal;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

What am I missing? Hours of ChatGPT has not resolved the issue. Thanks.
